# Using reflection copy object properties to another object

Tags: c#, reflection

HI,

I have code below but getting error "object does not match target type"
on the prop.SetValue statement. But the types are both Int32.

```
    private UniqueProjectType CreateUniqueProjectType(TBR.Domain.Project project)
    {
        UniqueProjectType type = new UniqueProjectType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Name == "ID")
            {}
            else if (prop.Name == "PayFrequency")
                type.PayFrequency = _tbrService.GetEmployee((int)project.EmployeeID).PayFrequency;
            else
                prop.SetValue(type, prop.GetValue(project, null), null);

        }

        return type;
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the declaration of `SetValue()` and `GetValue()` methods together with it's types otherwise we can only assume what is going on.

Comment: @Raphael B.: they are built-in .NET types

Comment: Maybe Raphael B. meant it would be helpful to see what field this is crashing on - need to know the data type, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here's the catch:

```
prop.GetValue(project, null);
```

prop is specific to `UniqueProjectType` while `project` is `TBR.Domain.Project` type. I think you should get all properties of `TBR.Domain.Project` and find one that has corresponding name.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call GetValue on the PropertyInfo corresponding to the Project type. PropertyInfo instances are tied to a specific type.

Basically, for each property info of the UniqueProjectType type, you have to look for a PropertyInfo on the Project type with the same name. Then you call GetValue and SetValue for the two objects using their corresponding PropertyInfo.